# Link sales table to a discount ON/OFF table

Tags: join, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables in a SQL environment. One show if we have activated a discount for certain customers as TRUE or FALSE. The second indicates the orders we receive and its time. I want to find the status of the discount toggle when the order arrived. What was the last change for that scope?

Discount status changes:

| customer vertical | type | time | Discount_Toggle_ON_OFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Automotive | B | 10/12/2023 10:30 | TRUE |
| Automotive | B | 10/12/2023 10:35 | FALSE |
| Automotive | B | 10/12/2023 12:30 | TRUE |
| Automotive | B | 11/12/2023 15:30 | FALSE |
| Retail | A | 10/12/2023 10:30 | FALSE |
| Retail | A | 10/12/2023 10:45 | TRUE |
| Retail | A | 12/12/2023 10:30 | FALSE |
| Retail | A | 15/12/2023 10:30 | TRUE |
| Retail | A | 20/12/2023 10:30 | FALSE |

Orders where last column is the deserved result:

| ORDER_CODE | type | customer vertical | time | was_discount_on? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA1 | B | Automotive | 10/12/2023 10:31 | ???? (it should be TRUE) |
| AAAAA2 | B | Automotive | 10/12/2023 11:00 | ???? (it should be FALSE) |
| AAAAA3 | A | Automotive | 10/12/2023 10:31 | ???? (it should be NA as there is no reference for automotive -A) |
| AAAAA4 | A | Retail | 17/12/2023 10:31 | ???? (it should be TRUE) |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (Please edit your question to use formatted text.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL 5.x, MySQL 8+, SQLite, SQL Server, etc?

Comment: Spark SQL in databricks

Answer (score 0):

Find all the rows lower than the time of order and take the row with most recent time from `discount_status_change` to get the most recent discount status that is being applied to the order.

Note - Make sure your timestamp columns are timestamps

```
SELECT
    O."ORDER_CODE",
    O."type", O."customer vertical", 
    O."time", 
    DISCOUNT_STATUS_CHANGE."Discount_Toggle_ON_OFF",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY "ORDER_CODE"
        ORDER BY DISCOUNT_STATUS_CHANGE."time" DESC
    ) AS RN
FROM
    ORDERS O
    LEFT JOIN DISCOUNT_STATUS_CHANGE ON DISCOUNT_STATUS_CHANGE."customer vertical" = O."customer vertical"
    AND DISCOUNT_STATUS_CHANGE."type" = O."type"
    AND O."time" >= DISCOUNT_STATUS_CHANGE."time"
QUALIFY RN = 1
```

**Output:**

[image]

[`here`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oyjKG6AvRqiBpMAwXwTHaR/1) is db-fiddle link for what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT
    T1.ORDER_CODE,
    T1.type, 
    T1.customer_vertical, 
    T1.time, 
    D.Discount_Toggle_ON_OFF
FROM
    ORDERS T1
    LEFT JOIN DISCOUNT_STATUS_CHANGE D 
       ON D.customer_vertical = T1.customer_vertical
      AND D.type = T1.type
      AND T1.time >= D.TIME
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 
           FROM DISCOUNT_STATUS_CHANGE DD
          WHERE DD.customer_vertical = D.customer_vertical
            AND DD.type = D.type
            AND DD.TIME > D.TIME
            AND DD.TIME <= T1.TIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT
      d.discount_toggle_on_off 
    FROM
      discount   AS d
    WHERE
          d.customer_vertical = o.customer_vertical
      AND d.type              = o.type
      AND d.time             <= o.time
    ORDER BY
      d.time DESC
  )  
FROM
  orders   AS o
```